# Can .net generate smtp calendar appointments like it does messages?

Tags: asp.net, .net, outlook

I am trying to get .net to generate calendar appointments to user’s outlook such that the recipient would get a meeting request.
All the examples on the web have a standard message/ email object with an .ics attachment that contains the meeting details.

This is not good because I require the inbound outlook interaction to not be a message in the inbox , but rather an appointment in their calendar.
Secondly, these appointments can contain attachments similar to standard messages/ emails.

Is this possible with native .net? how about third party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

The format for publishing calendar data is iCalendar (its like smtp for calenders and is used in most Outlook style applications.

I tested DDay.iCal library for this and it worked fine for me.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/

It produces a stream formatted in iCalendar format which can be saved to disk, emailed, or returned from a web site. In your case if you are SMTP then attaching an iCalendar format file as an attachment should do the trick.

Comment: will teh recipient be able to accept, reject or select tentative to the meeting request? i need bi-directional comunication with updates and ststus of meeting details between outlook and asp.net UI driven off of a sql database that parses the objects for the UI

Comment: In order to have interactive you need to publish an iCalendar endpoint on your web server. This endpoint would have URL protocol of webcal:// and is expected to return and accept data in iCalendar format (not HTML). When a user clicks on this (typically presented as an <a href> in a mail link or via a web page, their browser notices the webcal:// protocol and adds that online calender to their local Outlook. Online calendars have a facility to "add calendar" and the user then types in the webcal:// URL. Calendars from multiple sources are supported by most online calendar apps.